# Significance of 'ฯ' in English orthography

Tags: orthography, written-language, punctuation

The special characters page of my English keyboard on Android contains what appears to be a Thai character (ฯ). I've so far found that it is used as a kind of punctuation or phrase-shortening particle in Thai orthography, but haven't had any success figuring out why it's on my keyboard. I can only assume that it has some broader significance. What (if any) usage does this character have outside of Thai that justifies its presence on a standard issue phone keyboard?

[image]

Comment: Can I get a downvote explanation? If the question is considered off topic, I'll overhaul it to be more relevant.

Comment: Language and character identification questions are generally off-topic here. I have a guess what it is, nevertheless.

Comment: @jknappen any suggestions as to where I should take questions of this sort in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Some tries to answer such a question: Search the character (cut-and-pasted) in wikipedia or wiktionary, or try to find it on the site http://unicode.org

Comment: It can't be a Thai symbol on the English kbd. Unless you show us a screenshot of the keyboard layout, we cannot make any wild guesses. Voting to close as Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Where did you get your phone, Alex? Perhaps in Thailand? Can it be a bug in the localization of some Chinese branded phone?

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan I've uploaded a screenshot of the keyboard. It doesn't strike me as a bug, but I could be wrong

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B8%AF

Comment: @user6726 I found that page also, which is actually why I thought this was an appropriate question for Linguistics SE, since I'm really looking for a usage explanation, not just a character id. Unless that Thai character is sharing a codepoint with an identical character from a different orthography, I can't image why it would be available as a special char

Comment: The normal English keyboard wouldn't have the upside down ? or !, or any of those Greek letters. I doubt you are actually looking at an English keyboard.

Comment: On my (different) Android phone, the “symbols” keyboard is independent of the language of the “main” keyboard (Sample: English, French, German and Greek). I guess it is the same here, with a “symbols” keyboard designed to accommodate a Thai “main” keyboard if needed

Comment: @FrédéricGrosshans I investigated mine and found that English, Spanish, and German use the same symbols keyboard. However, the Japanese one is different and does not include ฯ

Comment: And I wish people in this StackExchange who find the correct answer (as occurred a year ago) would post it as an answer, rather than let people be mislead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alex Clough: this symbol (ฯ) is a Thai symbol that demonstrates that the word(s) before it has been abbreviated; for whatever reason, the lexicologists/orthographers working with the text recognition software and the decision of what characters to include in the creation of the keyboard for their product decided that this character was recognizable enough and used by enough people to warrant inclusion.

The first website explains it very concisely, the second one isn't quite as clear but gives several examples of how it isn't necessarily restricted to just the previous word, but also the phrase (to some degree, I can't be entirely sure, I don't speak Thai).

https://www.thai2english.com/dictionary/1264953.html

https://www.thai2english.com/dictionary/1458563.html

I hope this was helpful!!

Comment: See also https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ฯ. Unicode U+0E2F, &#3631;
THAI CHARACTER PAIYANNOI. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_11940: "ISO 11940:1998 distinguishes the abbreviation symbol paiyannoi (ฯ) from the sentence terminator angkhandiao (ฯ), even though neither the national character standard TIS 620-2533 nor Unicode Version 5.0 distinguishes them."  (cont)

Comment: http://www.thailandqa.com/forum/showthread.php?4830-Special-characters-in-thai-language: "Paiyan Noi (ฯ) is an abbreviation sign, representing omitted text. Its function is like elipsis, although the more correspondent Thai punctuation mark for elipsis is Paiyan Yai (ฯลฯ).". https://www.nectec.or.th/it-standards/thaistd.pdf: "Paiyan Noi (7) or omission sign, and Mai Yamok (8) or repetition sign, are contemporary punctuation marks generally used in documents."

Comment: Is this symbol used in combination with text in the Latin Script (e.g., English text or Thai transcribed into Latin Script)?

Comment: This is a better answer since it addresses the usage of the character I actually have rather than conjecturing that it was supposed to be a Tironian note (a codepoint lookup confirms that it really is encoded as a Thai character on my keyboard).